# Personal modification Angluar CLI - Creating a new app

Tags: angular, new-operator

Hi Stackoverflow Community,

I have the following question / problem.

Is there a way to create an own (more individually) ng new script ?

The standard command

```
ng new projectname
```

just allow me to create or not create routing, set scss or css.

When creating a new app, I want some specials (for example ask or automatic install bootstrap)

In other words, I want to make a more individual ng new command

Answer (score 0):

Does the manual help you?

See: https://angular.io/cli/new

There you have a lot of options which you can set. For example --collection options which is very powerful.
With --collection you can pass a schematic.

A very good Schematic example you can find here:

https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/02/13/angular-schematics